# How to apply the same jQuery code to two instances of the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

For instance I have this code:

```
$('.note .exit').click(function() {
  $('.note').fadeOut();
});
```

And on my HTML there are two instances of .exit and .note. As in:

```
<div class="note">
        <img src="images/exit.png" class="exit"/>

        <p>Some text.</p>   
</div>

<div class="note">
        <img src="images/exit.png" class="exit"/>

        <p>Some other text.</p> 
</div>
```

The problem is when I click the close button (exit image) of one .note, the other .note also closes. How do I revise the code so that it only applies to that particular .note class that I am closing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.closest()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the closest ancestor that matches a selector:

```
$('.note .exit').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.note').fadeOut();
});
```

Given your structure, you could also use [`.parent()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Comment: OP actually doesn't need to bind to the nested image. Just binding the click to the parent `.note` whilst using `$(this).fadeOut()` should be fine.

Comment: @jAndy: Depends, maybe he does not want to close the note if the user clicks anywhere else inside of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I need. :D +1 vote to other helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this).parent().fadeOut()` ... `this` will be the `.exit` on which the click happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 $('.note .exit').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.note').fadeOut();
});
```